# Conditional type based on union string with typescript

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have the following interfaces:

```js
interface IPargraph {
    id: number,
    value: string
}

interface ITask {
    id: number,
    date: Date
}
```

and the following union type:

```js
export type BodyTypes = "PARAGRAPH" | "TASK" | "IMAGE"
```

how would I make it so the data property in the following interface will be either `ITask` or `IParagraph` based on the value of `type`

```js
export interface INoteBody {
  type: BodyTypes
  data: **ITask or IParagraph based on which BodyTypes is used**
}
```

For example, this shouldn't be valid:

```js
const note: INoteBody = {
    type: "PARAGRAPH",
    data: {
        id: 1,
        date: new Date()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you *need* `BodyTypes` to be a union of string literals, or could you instead use a union of the interfaces?

Comment: @MajorProductions Sure, I can use a union of the interface. But how can I ensure if type is "PARAGRAPH" that the date property wouldn't be valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```ts
interface IPargraph {
    id: number
    value: string
}

interface ITask {
    id: number
    date: Date
}

export type BodyMap = {
  "PARAGRAPH": IPargraph
  "TASK": ITask
  "IMAGE": any
}

type BodyType = keyof BodyMap

export interface INoteBody<T extends BodyType> {
  type: T
  data: BodyMap[T]
}

const date: INoteBody<"TASK"> = {
  type: "TASK",
  data: {
    id: 2,
    date: new Date(),
  },
}

const paragraph: INoteBody<"PARAGRAPH"> = {
    type: "PARAGRAPH",
    data: {
        id: 1,
        value: 'any value',
    },
}
```

It is also possible to change from `interface` to `type`, to avoid the explicit Generic:

```ts
type INoteGeneric<T> = T extends keyof BodyMap ? {
    type: T;
    data: BodyMap[T];
} : never;

type INote = INoteGeneric<keyof BodyMap>;

const dateWithType: INote = {
  type: "TASK",
  data: {
    id: 2,
    date: new Date(),
  },
}

const paragraphWithType: INote = {
    type: "PARAGRAPH",
    data: {
        id: 1,
        value: 'any value',
    },
}
```

[Live test](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAU5QOZTgBwAtkBvAKGUuWABMAuZEAVwFsAjaCqgNzgBsmEBgGcwUUNjIBfMmVCRYiFKgAqcYQGtSXSrQbN2nKshpxIDACJmI02RAAe+APZQwyMAE98KAEJOaHgCyBMgAvNqUAEToAIIASjEA4gnoABKRDBhYuASEXJEqMQDKANIZaGqa+aiBSQCi5XAgHrZknt7IfgEqXijhGhAeTjCd-kEEdo4ubvLQ8EhoAHJOkF0eADwqyA6QIDTCo929AHwR7r0MKlymYHAMa8H4ANoqALqtCE4goibWmcurMbrArFMqncLkSjtITIEGlSIAGmuZjuZ109GQACYkcYbjCQBAAO7IKyQAAUAEoccgpEiZGRPt83PgsHAckR-isIGtgbEEskYmlIuC0edvAxovEkil0tTKDdUZDjFQ9MgAIxy5W8AQwgDkTQ8yG1gl1mtprVkAHpLaFbXb7Q7HU7nU7ZG1eksuYkIATxAhNiKtjsfftkAMhiMHiEAPyi6GXADcOl+t3uY0eL1eSakyH0EG40CT7o6qABfU9kG9vuA-vDw0O43wxyLjJ+eIA6sAwIQeuKK+WlfHYYV4dSFQwleiGNjk3i88TSRBKdTzfTW8zWezCJ3u72YaWuWE4xdYXzpYLZbOURPk8ZVRrbzx+IIGPrmkbnxBTcnV0A)